# Tycho Configuration for plugin project for existing Junit Test. Note; [eclipse-plugin-test] will not work

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho

How to configure pom file type in tycho for plugin project for existing Junit test. Note; [eclipse-plugin-test] will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using eclipse-test-plugin and it should work

Comment: I tried it but this does not works. Plugin test will work by this approach.